# X-Gsm7Bit charset in JBoss 7.2

Tags: java, character-encoding, jboss

I am in the process of migrating from JBoss AS 5 to JBoss 7.2. We have an SMS application based on SMPP protocol. EAR contains a war and and ejb jar and three utility jars under lib folder. One of the SMPP requirement is to encode data in X-GSM7Bit before sending to the service provider.

I have created a module named charset and my ear has declared a dependency on it. However, at runtime it doesnt seem to be loaded at all.

This is what I have done as of now:

1. Create a module named charset
2. Create jboss-deployment-structure.xml in ear

   ```
   <jboss-deployment-structure>
     <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
     <deployment>
       <dependencies>
         <module name="com.quwic.msc" export="true"/>
         <module name="charset" services="import" export="true"/>
       </dependencies>
     </deployment>
     <sub-deployment name="MSCWeb.war">
       <dependencies>
         <module name="deployment.MSC.ear.MSCEJB.jar" />
       </dependencies>
     </sub-deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```

Could someone please point out what could be missing. Module charset contains a META-INF/services/java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider file pointing to the implementing class.

Thanks,
Atique